# Set bash TAB autocomplete parameter candidates for an executable

Tags: bash, jenkins, autocomplete

I have a bourne script that takes the name of an executable as a parameter and installs an executable archived by jenkins to the executable path.

```
root@host:~# cat `which jinstall`
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
    if ! [ -e "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$1/builds/$2/archive/$1" ]; then
        echo "$1 build $2 not found"
        exit 1
    fi

    rm /opt/user/bak/$1 2>/dev/null
    mv /opt/user/bin/$1 /opt/user/bak 2>/dev/null
    cp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$1/builds/$2/archive/$1 /opt/user/bin
    chown root:user /opt/user/bin/$1
    chmod 650 /opt/user/bin/$1
    ls -al /opt/user/bin/$1
else
    echo "Usage: jinstall <executable> <build_number>"
fi
```

**The question I have is:**  how do I set the bash autocomplete candidates for the parameters of this script?  This is for a BASH shell.

When I type in a command like "killall" and a few letters then press TAB, bash autocompletes the parameter with an executable name.  I'd like the parameter to autocomplete using an executable already in /opt/user/bin OR the name of a subdirectory of /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following bash script will enable desired autocompletion ***under the assumption that your filenames don't contain whitespace symbols***:

```
jinstall_completion() {
   COMPREPLY=(
       $(
           shopt -s nullglob;
           for x in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/"$2"* /opt/user/bin/"$2"*
           do
               basename "$x"
           done|sort -u
       )
   );
}

complete -o filenames -F jinstall_completion jinstall
```

Comment: I put this code in a /etc/bash_completion.d/jinstall and it works.  tyvm!

Comment: I also changed the function name to __jinstall_completion to prevent auto-completion in the shell and added:

if [ \`which jinstall|wc -l\` -eq 0 ]; then return; fi to restrict non-root users

tyvm